# SBT/Play: Trouble resolving artifacts in Ivy Repository (Artifactory)

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

Updated with latest, thanks to @JamesWard for showing how to update to force Ivy.

We use gradle as our build system (java).  I decided trying to get Play going with Gradle was probably going against the grain too much, so I just want to consume artifact dependencies from SBT.

I want to get a simple play app going using one of our libraries in our Artifact Rep (Artifactory).

I tried doing this in build.sbt:

```
name := "NervTwitter"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools" % "scala-stm_2.9.1" % "0.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.myco.eda" % "eda-nerv-core" % "latest.milestone"


resolvers += Resolver.url("MyCO Artifactory", url("http://bas.eur.ad.sag:8081/artifactory/repo"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

I then ran show compile:dependencyClasspath from play console and get:

```
[warn] ==== MyCO Artifactory: tried
[warn]   http://bas.eur.ad.sag:8081/artifactory/repo/com.myco.eda/eda-nerv-core/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Note the `/repo/com.myco.eda/` .  This is incorrect, in our repo the correct path is: `/repo/com/myco/eda/`

So it's resolving Ivy(good), but the format isn't correct.  I *think* I need to make my ivy repo maven2 compatible.  But I'm not sure how....

Here is a reference to how our repo is laid out:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:ivy_repositories

look under:  50.6.6.2. Ivy repository with Maven compatible layout

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("MyCO Artifactory", url("http://mycorepo:8081/artifactory/repo"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

More details: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html

Comment: Closer I think = it now looks like it's trying Ivy:  ==== MyCO Artifactory: tried
[warn]   http://bas.eur.ad.sag:8081/artifactory/repo/com.myco.eda/eda-nerv-core/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml  But that resolver isn't quite right.  "com.my.co.eda" should actually be "com/myco/eda"

Comment: How is the `eda-nerv-core` library being published?  Are you sure it's published in the Ivy style?